# Placing a Segmented Picker inside a Menu in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, menu, picker

I'm trying to have a segmented style Picker() inside a Menu() but it isn't showing.
Here's some code:

```
struct MenuView: View {
var pick = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
@State var selected = "1"
var body: some View {
    Menu {
        Button{
        } label: {
            Text("Button1")
        }
        
        Picker("select one", selection: $selected) {
            ForEach(pick, id: \.self){
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        
    } label: {
        Text("Menu")
    }
}}
```

It works with .menu and .inline styles, but I would prefer to have it as .segmented.
Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this cannot be done in standard ways. If you need to do this, you will need to create your own custom menu.